# OpenCms 9 module Search: don't work search in Cyrillic (Ukrainian)

Tags: search, module, locale, cyrillic, opencms

I've a website mounted with OpenCms 9 and use integral module Search. 
My website is available in Ukranian (Cyrillic). Is it posible force Search module to show results in a specific locale (Ukrainian)? As far as I can judge the problem is in lack of localization module. If so where I can find one?

Answer (score 0):

I write a post in my blog to the explanation to set a new index i hope this help you [How to use solr in opencms](http://itidragoonpunk.blogspot.mx/2014/07/how-to-use-solr-in-opencms.html)

if you have al ready set the core index just test it with localhost/opencms/opencms/handleSolrSelect?fq=con_locales:es&core=Your index 

just change the locale for yours

the code will be something like this

```
CmsSolrResultList results = OpenCms.getSearchManager().getIndexSolr("Solr Online       Index").search(getCmsObject(), query);
```

the query example is

```
String query="fq=type:v8article&fq=lastmodified:[NOW-1DAY TO NOW]&fq=Title_prop:Flower";
```

See **16.2.2.3 Send Java-API query** in OpenCms-9.0.1 Documentation